# Is it possible to use Apple Wireless keyboard with Android 4.2.2 tablet?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, keyboard, bluetooth, kobo

I have a Kobo Arc 10HD and it runs on Android 4.2.2. I have successfully paired it with an Apple wireless keyboard but I still can't seem to use it. My virtual keyboard pops up and when I type on the Bluetooth keyboard nothing happens. Has anyone used a different keyboard that works? Is it even possible for me to use the Apple keyboard?

Comment: I remember using an Apple WK with an Asus Transformer tablet about a couple of years ago. I don't remember exactly which Android version it was, but it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the keyboard is properly paired, have you tried using the excellent [External Keyboard Helper Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper&hl=en_GB)? I use it with a Microsoft Bluetooth keyboard, and it handles both switching to the external keyboard from the internal one (and back) when needed, but also little chores like nuking the caps lock key.